# Capturing Id attribute to an Array by JSoup?

Tags: java, html, filter, jsoup

I'm using the library Jsoup, is that I have a string with two HTML components with the attribute ID to all, I want to do is capture the two IDs in an array.

```
String chain = "<div id='stylized' class='myform' style='margin:20px auto;'>
            <div id='material_comprado'  > </div> ";
```

I was trying to use this for, but failed.

```
int i = 0;
Elements values = doc.getElementsByAttribute("id");
String s[] = new String[values.size()];
for(Element el : values){
    s[i++] = el.attr("id");
    System.out.println("==> "+s[i]);
}
```

Anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `JSoup` code itself is fine.

You're incrementing the array index for `s` beyond its upper bound resulting in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when you attempt to display the element. Increment the index *after* youve finished accessing the array

```
for (Element el : values){
    s[i] = el.attr("id");
    System.out.println("==> " + s[i]);
    i++; // now safe to increment
}
```